# How much energy was used to charge the inductor? Electrical systems question

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance, electrical-engineering

I am a math major, and I am taking a mandatory class that looks more like physics and the professor gave us an assignment with a question that I don't have any idea on how to solve it. The question is originally in portuguese, so, I will try my best to translate.

In t = 0, a battery is connected to an inductor with inductance L. At the instant T, the current in the inductor is constant. How much energy was used to charge the inductor?

The question is general, without any explicit number. If anyone can help me, I would be grateful. I feel like it's simple, but I don't even know how to start.

The professor is using the following book: Modern Control Engineering by Katsuhiko Ogata (this problem is not here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an inductor (with inductance $L$) the defining relation
between voltage ($V$) and current ($I$) is:
$$V(t)=L\frac{dI(t)}{dt} \tag{1}$$

To find the total energy $E$ fed into the inductor
you need to integrate the power ($VI$) over time $t$ (from $0$ to $T$).
Then use equation (1), and finally do the integration by substitution.
$$E=\int_0^T V(t)\ I(t)\ dt
  = \int_0^T L\frac{dI(t)}{dt}\ I(t)\ dt
  = \int_0^{I(T)} L\ I\ dI
  = \frac{1}{2}L\ I(T)^2$$

So the energy depends only on the final current,
but not on the explicit time course of the current $I(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The battery delivers a constant voltage $V$. The voltage of an inductor follows the differential equation: $$V = L\frac{dI}{dt}$$ where $L$ is the inductance and  $I$ is the current. And the energy is the integral of the power $E = \int{VI dt}$